# Can't bind event in jquery mobile dynamic list on a mobile browser

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I'm developing a relatively simple jQuery mobile site which interacts with my server through an AJAX call and then updates a list view based on the values returned. The dynamic update works fine but the `click` event doesn't seem to get bound to the dynamic list items on mobile browsers. (Same results in Android and iOS) but works fine in both Chrome, Firefox and Safari on the desktop.

Here's the code that populates my list (this works on desktop and mobile):

```
$('#searchfield').keypress(function(e) {
    if( $(this).val().length > 3 ) {
        $.getJSON('admin.php?request=search&srch_email=' + $(this).val(), function(data) {
            if( data.status == 'success' ) {
                 $('#results').empty();
                 $.each(data.data, function(count,user) {
                 $('#results').append('<li><a href="#profile_' + user.uid + '" class="profile">' + user.first_name + ' ' + user.last_name + ' (' + user.email + ')</a></li>');
                     $('#results').listview('refresh');
                     users[user.uid] = user;
                 });
             }
        });
     }
     else if($(this).val().length == 0 ) {
         $('#results').empty();
     }
});
```

To bind the events I originally tried:

```
$('.profile').live('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var parts = $(this).attr('href').split("_");
    var user = users[ parts[1] ];

    $('#pheader').html('Edit User ' + user.email );

    $('#fname').val(user.first_name);
    $('#lname').val(user.last_name);
    $('#zip').val(user.zipfirst);
    $('#state').val(user.state);

    $('.uid').val(user.uid);

    $.mobile.changePage( $('#profile') );
    $('#searchfield').val("");
    $('#results').empty();

});
```

That didn't work so I read that `.live()` may not work correctly on mobile and `.on` is now the preferred method. I changed the first line of the above to:

```
$('#results').on('click',".profile", function(e) {
```

Same result though.

**Edit** when I say it's failing it's that the button simply doesn't respond. There are no console errors, it just acts like it's not a clickable button.

Comment: Your event delegation appears to be properly coded. I would watch your console for errors. Also, what does `That didn't work...` actually mean? Did you get an error message, or did it die silently, or?

Comment: No errors in the console. Didn't work as in nothing happened at all. It acted as though it wasn't clickable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer. Changing

`$('#results').on('click',".profile", function(e) {`

to

`$('#results').on('vclick',".profile", function(e) {`

Solved it on mobile.

Answer (score 0):

you can try using onclick function..

```
$('#searchfield').keypress(function(e) {
if( $(this).val().length > 3 ) {
    $.getJSON('admin.php?request=search&srch_email=' + $(this).val(), function(data) {
        if( data.status == 'success' ) {
             $('#results').empty();
             $.each(data.data, function(count,user) {
            var param = "'"+ user.uid +"'";
             $('#results').append('<li><a href="#" class="profile" onclick="testFunction('+ param +')">' + user.first_name + ' ' + user.last_name + ' (' + user.email + ')</a></li>');
                 $('#results').listview('refresh');
                 users[user.uid] = user;
             });
         }
    });
 }
 else if($(this).val().length == 0 ) {
     $('#results').empty();
 }
```

});

In testFunction,

```
function testFunction(userID){

   var user = users[ userID ];

   $('#pheader').html('Edit User ' + user.email );

   $('#fname').val(user.first_name);
   $('#lname').val(user.last_name);
   $('#zip').val(user.zipfirst);
   $('#state').val(user.state);

   $('.uid').val(user.uid);

   $.mobile.changePage( $('#profile') );
   $('#searchfield').val("");
   $('#results').empty();
}
```